# ClearType keeps reseting (disabling) every time I restart windows

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

At work, I have a machine in which some fonts look awful, so I need to turn on ClearType to make them look good, and it works perfectly fine.

But whenever I restart the machine, Windows keeps reseting the option, as if I never set it before, and I have to go through the process again.

Why could it be, and how can I avoid it to reset ClearType each time I restart the machine?

machine specs:

- model: HP 120-1015la
- OS: Windows 7 Home Basic, Service Pack 1, 64 bit.

Comment: Since this is at work, do you know if your settings are controlled by Group Policy or a Logon Script? If you have an IT department / person you may want to check with them?

Comment: I really dont think they use Group Policies or anything, neither we are in a Domain or those kind of stuff. I have admin privileges at the machine, so where could I check?

Comment: No domain  joining or GP with Home Basic, that's for sure. :/

Comment: Does it still reset if you create a new user to set/test with?

Comment: ...I made a new test user, started session, ClearType was already on. Turned it off, got back to MY user, and CT was on (so i guess it is indeed a per-user setting). Got back to new user, turned it on again. closed session on new user, and started it again, CT was still on. I yet have to try to turn off the machine (instead of just ending session) to see if it restarts for both me and the new test user. I'll let you know when I do that.

Comment: Does it happen in [Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) too? Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) already?